# wakelock inside a running thread Android

Tags: android, multithreading, wakelock

I have this simple question:

In a service i need to run 2 more threads independent from each other, and i need a wakelock to let them be executed. I give you an example:

```
   wl.aquire();

    if (true) {
        mExecutorService.execute(thread1);
    }

    if (true) {
        mExecutorService.execute(thread2);
    }
   wl.release();
```

So, in this case, the wake lock will be released once the 2 threads have started or does it wait for them to finish?

If not, i need the wakelock to stay up while they're running, and release it only when the last thread has finished. How can i do that? Do i have to acquire new wakelocks inside the thread's body?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Executor `execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29) documentation: "Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation."

So it depends on which concrete Executor you are using.

I think you are supposed to use [`submit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to give a new job to an Executor.

If you stick with the Executor, calling `get()` on the Future returned by `submit()` will block until the result is available.

So you could call:

```
Future<Result> result_1 = mExecutorService.execute(Runnable1);
Future<Result> result_2 = mExecutorService.execute(Runnable2);

result_1.get();
result_2.get();
```

Alternatively, you could start two threads and wait for them to finish:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(Runnable1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(Runnable2);
t1.start();
t2.start();

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely the right way. By the way, isnt'it executor.submit() instead of execute()?

Comment: At the end i added a new wakelock section, because waiting on the executor to get(), sent me to the "Force Close, Wait" problem. By the way, thanks for your answer. This should be the correct way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running this code from `AsyncTask` or background thread. You can call `[Thread.join()]` on all the threads before the call to `wl.release();`

check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) for `join()` detail

EDIT1: on executor you can also use [awaitTermination()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) with long wait value to wait for it to finish all the tasks. Following code is from the official [java doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. That could be a solution. So with an executor we can use the .get() command. So you're saying that the wakelock immediatily release when threads are started?

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html -- the correct way would be to acquire the wakelocks inside the two threads you are running. Given your example code, you will need a member variable inside thread1 and thread2 to store the wakelock, and some way to pass the wakelock in, perhaps like this:

```
thread1.setWakelock(wl);
thread2.setWakelock(wl);

class Thread implements Runnable {
    PowerManager.Wakelock mWakelock;
    void setWakelock(PowerManager.Wakelock wl) {
        mWakelock = wl;
    }
}
```

Then inside thread1 and thread2, you will need:

```
run() {
    mWakelock.acquire();
    ... your existing code here ...
    mWakelock.release();
}
```

Note that this will work since wake locks are reference counted by default; see PowerManager.WakeLock.setReferenceCounted().

Waiting for the threads to finish using thread.join() is wrong; it will block the UI thread and you will get an ANR, as you found out.

Comment: That's how I decided to developed it. I made a custom Runnable with a WakeLock parameter in its cunstructors. Just simply check if it's held on the run() method and then I acquire the WL